# How to create a `Vector` from `DataFrame` in Apache Spark ML API?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to create a `Vector`(import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{DenseVector, SparseVector}) from `DataFrame` in Apache Spark ML API?

Comment: You'll need to give more information to get a useful answer. What is the shape of your DataFrame (is it a single column, or multiple)? If multiple, do you want one vector per column? Do you want one per row? Since you're using Spark, I assume you can't fit your DataFrame in memory. How do you expect to fit the Vectors in memory? One per node or something else?

Comment: would you mind updating the question as suggested in comment above

Answer (score -1):

If you want `scala.collection.Vector`
You can just collect DataFrame and call `toVector()` function.

```
val df = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF
val vector = df.collect().toVector
vector.map(_.getInt(0))
```

p. s. please explain why got a downvote

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote. Maybe because it produces vector of rows instead of vector of ints. Hard to tell, because the question seems unclear.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Question never mentions what type `T` of `Vector[T]` should it be. In my opinion, the question is too broad.

Comment: That's true, as I said, the question seems unclear. But your proposal would return `Vector[Row]` regardless of what type `T` is, instead of a `Vector[T]`, which is probably what the OP wanted... But, who knows what OP wanted?